# Facing Queued issue on Deployment in Relaxed Web Services

Tags: drupal-8

Drupal8 i installed Relaxed module, through that i am trying to deploy content from stage site to live site. while deploying content is going queue its not displaying on the live-site i have already checked configurations of Relaxed modules all the libraries and dependent modules are installed. even i also checked into status report its showing valid with no error.

How to deploy content to the live site from the staging site?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attachment not available

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to push the content from the staging environment to the live environment.

Create content and try to push it through the "Deploy" button & when you go to the "Deployments" page you will see the content was "Queued".

Here is the step try to run the CRON job from the admin side or use the command line for it:

```
drush core-cron.
```

Maybe sometimes due to the search indexing effect also the content you created might be not indexed properly.

Here use the commands:

```
drush sapi-r
drush sapi-i
```

Then try using:

```
drush core-cron.
```